# Anchor tag not displayed as button using twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, anchor

I'm using twitter bootstrap 3.0 and trying to display an anchor tag as a button using

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Add button</a>
```

But it is not showing as a button

[image]

When I use

```
<button class="btn"> Add button</button>
```

it is displayed as expected

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Add button</a>
```

add btn-default

Comment: This makes it look like a button but now the styling is totally different from my other buttons just using class="btn".

Comment: you should have btn-default on all button items.

Comment: Ok, I suppose that will have to do. Thanks